Maven build hanging after build is successfull on gitlab runner registered on Windows machine
I do have a windows 11 machine where i downloaded, installed, registered a gitlabrunner vers. 17+, runner is online visible in the gitlab instance.
I have maven installed and under path, java JDK 21, etc. on the windows 11 machine (all working fine).
When I trigger a gitlab run having a maven build from yaml file, even simplest command i.e. "maven clean install", gitlab job runs, maven build appears as successful in the gitlab logs, but in the end gitlab job remains hanging until timeout (timeout is set for 30 min).
If i trigger manually the maven build in the terminal everything works fine on the windows machine, build is successful and command finishes gracefully.
If i enter an echo command in the yaml file, and execute the gitlab job, it works fine, and the windows based gitlab runner ends gracefully (as expected).
Not sure what to verify or how to debug this, basically my goal is to be able to execute a maven command from the gitlab yaml file and the gitlab runner to run it succesfully without hanging when it finishes.
